REST API Server error using OAuth2 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
I have a simple REST API server with authentication based on OAuth2. Everything works as expected and I’m able to call the controllers by setting the correct bearer token. My goal is to manage authorization entirely and to do this, I wanted to use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity class.
However, as soon as I add the related configuration to my program.cs, the calls to the controller fail.
This is my program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration);


builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

This is my simple controller class:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class OAuthTestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("public")]
    public IActionResult GetPublicData()
    {
        return Ok("This is public data.");
    }

    [HttpGet("protected")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult GetProtectedData()
    {
        return Ok("This is protected data, you are authenticated.");
    }
}

If I try to call the GetProtectedData() endpoint using PostMan, the request is redirected to a login page that does not exist, and therefore I receive a 404 error.
Is it possible to use OAuth2 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity together? Is it better to manually create the tables to save users and roles?

You are using [authorize] which means the client credentials/role is used to access the route.  You didn't authorize any users or roles.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#using-the-authorize-attribute

As mentioned in the link, 'This filter checks whether the user is authenticated,' and indeed, by removing the Identity configuration part (builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()...), everything works as it should. If I authenticate with the bearer token, it works; otherwise, I receive a 401 error. The problem is when I add the Identity part.

I suspect the Arg may be wrong.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationoptions?view=aspnetcore-8.0#properties

the args variable is always an empty string

Based on my comprehension it is possible to combine this two. As asp.net core identity is default cookie auth, you might dig into this and get the error message as it is now a JWT auth.  My goal is to manage authorization entirely for this it is better to manually create the tables to meet your customization.

The arguements can either be a string[] or an object.  The string need to contain the same info as the object in the link.  I suspect the webrootpath is needed.  Can you put break points in the controller to see where you are failing?  I'm wondering if the route is correct.

I added the solution. It was enough to replace the AddIdentity function with the AddIdentityCore function. Thank you all for the help anyway.

As explained here, the solution to the problem is to use AddIdentityCore instead of AddIdentity.
Specifically, the code:
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

should be replaced with the code:
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(options => { }) 
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>() .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>() .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

